# Tags using select2 and symfony/doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, jquery-select2, symfony-forms, jquery-select2-4

I try to use the Select2 jQuery plugin with Symfony's form component and Doctrine to create a tag field where I can add existing tags and create new ones on the fly.

So far so good. I use the following Select2 init code:

```
$('select.tags').select2({
    tags: "true"
});
```

All existing tags get loaded on each request. New one's should be created/persisted on submitting the whole form. (So no AJAX magic.)

I don't know where I can hook in now to achieve this so that not existing tags get persisted to the database and added to my parent entity.

It has to happend somewhere between:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
}
```

and

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
}
```

in my controller. But I can't imagine what's the best way to do this (or if there is any).

[I read about form collection](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) but somehow this is not really what I need. Because there you have one single `input` field for each tag. But I have a `select` field with new options added dynamically.

Comment: Did you take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html ?

Comment: @Jay Thx for the hint I guess I need the `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` event then... so I created an EventSubscriber and registered it through `services.yml`. The `getSubscribedEvents()` method gets called. But the method registered for the event does not. Does it work to register event subscribers for `FormEvents` over the `services.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

> New one's should be created/persisted on submitting the whole form.

So why you don't want to persist them after this line:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
}
```

EDIT

Once I created the [transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) for tags. It changes collection of tags to single separated by commas. After submit the transformer turns back text to the collection Tags.

```
/**
 * Class TagTransformer
 * @package AppBundle\Form\Transformer
 *
 * @DI\Service("app.form.transformer.tag")
 */
class TagTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface{

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $em
     * @DI\InjectParams(params={
     *      "em" = @DI\Inject("doctrine.orm.entity_manager")
     * })
     */
    public function __construct($em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection | Tag[] $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function transform($value)
    {
        if($value == null) $value = array();

        $string = "";
        foreach($value as $tag)
            $string .= $tag->getName().",";
        return $string;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $value
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        $collection = new ArrayCollection();

        if(strlen($value) == 0) return $collection;

        $names = explode(",",$value);
        foreach($names as $name){
            $tag = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Def\Tag')->findOneByName($name);
            if(!$tag) $tag = new Tag();

            $tag->setName($name);
            $collection->add($tag);
        }

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because there are invalid options. The available options are all existing tags. But a new tag does not exist and is therefor invalid.

Answer (score 0):

once i did the same i seperated the logic from the formbuilder, right now i dont have the code but in pseudo:

be sure your chosen tags are written into an textinput as a string with some separator, sth. like

```
<input name="tags" value="tag1|tag2|tag3|" ..>
```

in controller you check if form is submitted and valid

then you have your entity

```
$entity=$form->getData()
```

and the tags

```
$tags = explode("|",$request->get('tags'));
```

then you iterate over them and add them to your entity, if the tag does not exist yet you create it

```
foreach($tags as $tag){
   $tag = $tagrepo->findOneByName($tag)
   if(!$tag){
     $newTag = new Tag();
     $newTag->setName($tag);
     $em->persist($newTag);
     $entity->addTag($newTag);
   }else{
     $entity->addTag($tag);
   }
  $em->flush();

}
```